# Error using WorksheetfFnction.match in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple problem that I am unable to solve. In my excel workbook in column A I have a set of dates. From this set of dates I want to find a specific date (the most recent date) and report the row number of the date. I can manage to find the date but not the row number. What I have done so far is:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

Dim maxdate As Date
Dim k As Integer
Dim row As Integer

maxdate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))

If maxdate < VBA.Date And maxdate > 0 Then
    row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(maxdate, Range("A:A"), 0)
    k = row
End If

If maxdate = 0 Then
    k = 0
End If

End Sub
```

When the line of code containing "row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match()" is executed VBA reports the error: Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class.

However, the correct maxdate is reported. I appreciate any input?

BR, Jesper

Answer (score 1):

**MATCH()** does not like **VBA** *Dates.* ....................so:

```
Option Base 1
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()

Dim maxdate As Date
Dim k As Long
Dim row As Long

maxdate = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A:A"))

If maxdate < VBA.Date And maxdate > 0 Then
    row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(maxdate), Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(row) Then 
        k = row
    Else:
        MsgBox maxdate & " not found!"
    End If
End If

If maxdate = 0 Then
    k = 0
End If
MsgBox k
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe preferable to `Dim row As Variant` and use the `Application.Match` instead, which can return an error value if the search string is not found. Then you can test `If IsError(row)...` to handle exceptions.

Comment: @DavidZemens Good idea!.....................would there be any advantage to using the **.Find()** method??

Comment: Also worth noting that if `Row` is integer, depending on the size of the table rows, that might raise an overflow error :)

Comment: @DavidZemens  I fixed **k** and **row**

Comment: IDK about the Find method, it's not a method that I use regularly and if I had to guess I'd say it is a more expensive operation than the `Match` function (but I have not tested to confirm that).